# Adding 2 column Layout for MailChimp HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, mailchimp

I'm in a tizzy here. I got a mailchimp layout which I exported from MailChimp. Right now the layout is 3 column, but in Mobile it's 1 column. 
Here is the codepen: goo.gl/Fj8Ct7

Can someone help me to get it to be 2 column layout in mobile view?
[image: example]

I'm in a real pickle here.

Best,
Mike

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `.columnWrapper` in your css where `max-width: 480px` from `width` 100% to 50%

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
        .columnWrapper{
            max-width:50% !important;
            width:50% !important;
}
```

### FINAL RESULT

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6WPT.png]

Comment: ! It worked like a charm. Great fix. Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Awesome... Glad I could help. If the answer is good, Mark it as correct